# Robot modeling in Unity using physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, modeling

I'm trying to imitate servos work in Unity for my project - modelling a physically accurate humanoid robot in unity and I need to simulate turning robot's parts (legs, knees) a certain degree. I tried to use hinge joint for this, but it soon became obvious that it makes robot be jiggly and kinda unpredictable. Right now I am trying to use configurable joint with zero projection (mode position and angle), but it sometimes makes robot to shake his parts continuously.

Which else options do I have to make robot more or less real-like (or like in Microsoft robotics dev studio), if i need to consider weight of each part?

Comment: why not rig it, and use skinned mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jiggling is often caused by the physics time step being too long. If you go to:

Edit -> Project Settings -> Time

and shorten the fixed timestep interval, you'll be able to get better physics simulation.

You can also add friction to the joints to make them a little less sensitive to resonance, but I'd try the timestep fix first.